# Flutter | How to use Provider with GridView.builder to prevent children rebuilds

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

**Situation**

I am trying to create a list which paginates data from Firestore using provider. Every item which is loaded into the GridView is a widget with an Image.memory component which downloads the image from Firebase Storage when the item is built. My problem is that as the provider adds more items to the list and notifies(), GridView obviously rebuilds as it is wrapped in a Selector, which rebuilds all children which causes them to download the images again, which is not desired.

*Provider*

```
class PaginateFirestoreProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  Query query;
  int documentLimit;

  PaginateFirestoreProvider(
      {required this.query, required this.documentLimit}) {
    fetch();
  }

  bool isLoading = false;
  bool isLoadingMore = false;
  bool hasMore = true;
  List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> items = [];
  DocumentSnapshot? lastDocument;

  bool get isListEmpty {
    return items.isEmpty;
  }

  Future fetch() async {
    if (!hasMore || isLoading) return;

    isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();

    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await query.limit(documentLimit).get();
    if (querySnapshot.docs.length < documentLimit) {
      hasMore = false;
    }
    lastDocument = querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 1];
    items.addAll(querySnapshot.docs);
    isLoading = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future fetchMore() async {
    if (!hasMore || isLoadingMore || lastDocument == null) return;

    isLoadingMore = true;
    notifyListeners();

    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await query
        .limit(documentLimit)
        .startAfterDocument(lastDocument!)
        .get();

    if (querySnapshot.docs.length < documentLimit) {
      hasMore = false;
    }
    lastDocument = querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 1];
    items.addAll(querySnapshot.docs);
    isLoadingMore = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

*GridView widget*

```
class PaginateFirestore extends StatefulWidget {
  Widget Function({required dynamic data}) itemBuilder;
  Widget emptyBuilder;
  Widget errorBuilder;
  Widget loadingBuilder;
  Widget loadingMoreBuilder;
  Query query;
  int pageSize;

  PaginateFirestore(
      {required this.itemBuilder,
      required this.query,
      required this.pageSize,
      required this.emptyBuilder,
      required this.errorBuilder,
      required this.loadingBuilder,
      required this.loadingMoreBuilder});

  @override
  State<PaginateFirestore> createState() => _PaginateFirestoreState();
}

class _PaginateFirestoreState extends State<PaginateFirestore> {
  late PaginateFirestoreProvider _paginateFirestoreProvider;

  bool isLoading = false;
  bool isLoadingMore = false;
  bool hasMore = true;
  List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> items = [];
  DocumentSnapshot? lastDocument;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<PaginateFirestoreProvider>(
      create: (context) {
        _paginateFirestoreProvider = PaginateFirestoreProvider(
            query: widget.query, documentLimit: widget.pageSize);
        return _paginateFirestoreProvider;
      },
      child: _buildPaginator(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPaginator() =>
      Selector<PaginateFirestoreProvider, Tuple2<bool, bool>>(
          selector: (context, value) =>
              Tuple2(value.isLoading, value.isListEmpty),
          builder: (context, value, child) => value.item1
              ? widget.loadingBuilder
              : value.item2
                  ? widget.emptyBuilder
                  : _buildList());

  Widget _buildList() => Column(
        children: [
          Selector<PaginateFirestoreProvider, List<QueryDocumentSnapshot>>(
              shouldRebuild: (previous, next) => true,
              selector: (context, value) => value.items,
              builder: (context, value, child) => GridView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: value.length,
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 3,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 1,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 1),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                      widget.itemBuilder(data: value[index].data()))),
          Selector<PaginateFirestoreProvider, bool>(
              selector: (context, value) => value.hasMore,
              builder: (context, value, child) => value
                  ? VisibilityDetector(
                      key: Key('my-widget-key'),
                      onVisibilityChanged: (visibilityInfo) {
                        if (visibilityInfo.visibleFraction > 0) {
                          _paginateFirestoreProvider.fetchMore();
                        }
                      },
                      child: widget.loadingMoreBuilder)
                  : SizedBox.shrink()),
        ],
      );
```

*List item* (passed as the itemBuilder parameter)

```
FutureBuilder(
              future: databaseService.getFileToMemory(
                  ref: pathToFile),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
                    snapshot.data != null) {
                  return Image.memory(
                    snapshot.data!,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: double.infinity,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) =>
                        _buildListItemError(),
                  );
                } else {
                  return _buildListItemError();
                }
              }),
```

**Question**

I need someway of adding the newly fetched items to the GridView without rebuilding all of them, while still using provider. Is this possible???